# Show full URL in emails sent using CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I'm sending emails using CakePHP. In the /View/Emails/html/newaccount.ctp file I'm doing something like:

```
<li>After you <?php echo $this->Html->link('log in', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'), true); ?> to your account...</li>
```

however I can't get full URLs to be sent in the email.

I've also tried the following with no luck:

```
<li>After you <?php echo $this->Html->link('log in', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'), array('fullBase' => true)); ?> to your account...</li>
```

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$url = Router::url(array("controller"=>"users","action"=>"login"),true);
```

Answer (score 1):

For those still looking, in CakePHP 3, I use the **_full** option:

```
 <?= $this->Html->link("Cancel my booking", [
                                '_full' => true,
                                "controller" => "bookings",
                                "action" => "modify",
                                $booking->id,
                               ]
                        )
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For further clarification, contrary to other `HtmlHelper` methods, in the `link()` method the full base option must currently go into the URL array, and it must be named `full_base`.

```
$this->Html->link('log in', array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'login',
    'full_base' => true
));
```

See also

- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/4199**